# This sum over partitions has unexpectedly nice denominators

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions, symmetric-functions, hilbert-schemes, localization

Fix an integer $n\geq0$, a power series $\gamma \in \mathbb Q[[X]]$ with valuation 1, and a symmetric function $f$ (with coefficients in $\mathbb Q$). Now, consider the series
$$
S_n = \sum_{\Lambda\in\text{2partitions} (n)} (-1)^{\ell(\Lambda)} \frac{(\ell(\Lambda)-1)!}{\operatorname{Aut}\Lambda} f( \{X(\square_1t_1 + \square_2t_2)\}_{i,\square \in \lambda_i}) \prod_i \prod_{\square \in \lambda_i} \frac{1}{\gamma(XT_1^\square) \gamma(X T_2^\square)}
$$
Here $t_1$ and $t_1$ are formal variables, and
$$
T_1^\square = (\operatorname{leg}(\square) + 1) t_1 - \operatorname{arm}(\square)t_2 ,\;\;\;\; T_2^\square= -\operatorname{leg}(\square)t_1 + (\operatorname{arm}(\square) +1)t_2
$$
(coming from to the tangent weights of a torus action on the Hilbert Scheme of points in $\mathbb C^2$).

The sum is over all ``2-partitions" of $n$, that is, a partition $\Lambda = (n_1, \dots , n_k)$ of $n$ together with partitions $\lambda_i$ of $n_i$. $\ell(\Lambda) = k$, the number of (first level) parts, the product over $i$ is from $1$ to $\ell(\Lambda)$, and $\operatorname{Aut}(\Lambda)$ is equal to the product of the factorials of the multiplicities of the parts of $\Lambda$ (ignore the subparts).

The product over $\square \in \lambda_i$ is over the cells of the diagram of the partition, and $(\square_1, \square_2)$ are the coordinates of the cell $\square$.

You expand the function $f$ in $n$ variables and plug in the given set.

If you expand $S_n$ in $X$, every coefficient will be a symmetric rational function of $t_1, t_2$, with degree equal to the exponent of $X$.

**Conjecture**
Each of these coefficients has denominator at most $t_1t_2$. (i.e. any coefficient times $t_1t_2$ is a polynomial.)

[Here are some supporting computations in Sage.](https://github.com/uberparagon/MOconjecture/blob/main/a%20conjecture.ipynb).

The coefficient $(-1)^{\ell(\Lambda)} \frac{(\ell(\Lambda)-1)!}{\operatorname{Aut}\Lambda}$ shows up in the formula for a general logarithm of a power series.

**Motivation**
I'm adding a little bit here about where this comes from. If you look at the localization formula for computing something of the form $\sum_n z^n\int_{(\mathbb C^2)^{[n]}} s((\mathcal O^r)^{[n]})$ or $\sum_n z^n \chi((\mathcal O^r)^{[n]})$,  then take its logarithm, and then take derivatives with respect to $r$, you get something of the form described here. Computational experiments suggested the property described here. The current form was generalized from this.

There is a conjecture relating these two generating series that I am interested in.

**Clarification**
I'm thinking of $f$ as an element of the ring of symmetric functions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_symmetric_functions). One can expand $f$ in any number of variables. For example, if $f$ were $e_1$ (the first elementary symmetric function), then $f(x,y,z) = x+y+z$ and $f(X(t_1 + t_2), X(t_1 + 2t_2)) = X(t_1 + t_2) + X(t_1 + 2t_2)$. Since $f$ is symmetric, the order of the variables doesn't matter, so it makes sense to plug in a set.

For the cells of a partition, I'm thinking of a Young diagram (English notation) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_of_symmetric_functions), and each cell has coordinators (with the row, column convention). So for example, the parition (3,1) of 4 would have cells with coordinates (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), and (2,1). Each cell also has an arm length and leg length (also defined in the link).

Comment: Maybe you can give some more motivation why you suspect this is true? It seems potentially interesting, but is it a generalization of something known? Does it have algebraic significance? etc.

Comment: What do you mean by “The sum over $\square \in \lambda_i$ is over the cells $(\square_1, \square_2)$ of the diagram of the partition.” There is only one sum in your formula, right? It runs over 2partitions $\Lambda$.

Comment: One more question. Why do you use this $\gamma$? It seems more natural to use $\gamma^{-1}$. I just want to write the main formula in the simplest possible way.

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin: It should be "The product over $\square \in \lambda_i$", I edited it, thanks. The way this came up from a localization it had the $\gamma$ in the denominator, but in this context I agree there is no good reason for that. We can rewrite it with no denominator.

Comment: @Drew ok, thanks. And what do you mean by “expand the function $f$ in $n$ variables and plug in the given set”? Shall we consider the function $f$ as a function in $n$ copies of variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_n$ (so each $X_i$ is an alphabet) and then substitute something for each $X_i$? And what are these $\square_1$ and $\square_2$? These symbols denote 1 and 2-boxes of $\Lambda$? How can we multiply them by $t_1$ and $t_2$?

Comment: @Drew One more question about the notation: “The product over $\square \in \lambda_i$ is over the cells $(\square_1, \square_2)$ of the diagram of the partition.” This $\square$ is a box of $\lambda_i$ or $\square=(\square_1,\square_2)$ is a box of $\Lambda$? But in formulas for $T_1^{\square}$ and $T_2^{\square}$ we have neither $\square_1$ nor $\square_2$? Could you, please, provide more details about the notation concerning 2Partitions?

Comment: @NikitaSafonkin I added a clarification section, and I updated the sentence "The product over..." to indicate that the cells have coordinates (instead of being the coordinates). Let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @Drew Thank you! It’s much better now.